# SMTP error for php emailer

Tags: php

I am trying to set up a php script that would send an email to selected users, I looked on the internet and found out how but can't run the script cos I get the following error:

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]:
>   "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or
>   custom "From:" header missing in
>   E:\Program
>   Files\xampp\phpMyAdmin\emailer.php on
>   line 10

Here is the code of the script I designed following examples:

```
<?php
    $recipient = "<ismael.srcyber@gmail.com>";
    $subject = "Flight Status";
    $body = "Flight has just landed.";

    $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
    $port = "465";


    if(mail($recipient, $subject, $body))
    {
        echo("<p>Message successfully sent</p>");
    }
    else
    {
        echo("<p>Message Delivery failed </p>");
    }
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to pass additional headers as the error is saying you are missing the from part check the php mail function doc they have example of headers

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggest you must add the default "from" field (who sends the mail) in php.ini:

```
SMTP = localhost


sendmail_from = me@localhost.com
```

And then restart apache

Otherwise you can set it dinamically as the fourth parameter as stated in the php manual (look http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

> Note:
>
> When sending mail, the mail must
>   contain a From header. This can be set
>   with the additional_headers parameter,
>   or a default can be set in php.ini.
>
> Failing to do this will result in an
>   error message similar to Warning:
>   mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in
>   php.ini or custom "From:" header
>   missing. The From header sets also
>   Return-Path under Windows.

Example:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```